# How to boot CoreOS with different ramdisk size

Tags: ramdisk, coreos

I am trying to boot CoreOS from a PXE server using ramdisk. 
However, no matter what size of ramdisk I specify (with ramdisk_size) CoreoOS always takes half of the memory as a ramdisk.
Can anyone tell me how to specify the ramdisk size at boot?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic because this question is not directly about programming. Please transfer this question to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has to do with the default nature of temporary filesystems in that they will default to 50% as the limit but won't reserve that much memory; actual usage will grow over time, but will not exceed the 50% limit.

Also you'll find this in the [official CoreOS docs regarding PXE](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/booting-with-pxe/#setting-up-pxelinux.cfg):

> The filesystem will consume more RAM as it grows, up to a max of 50%.
>   The limit isn't currently configurable.